# Debug ASP.NET with cURL commands

Tags: asp.net, curl

Is there a way to debug your web applications, when cURL is fired up?

- Run web application in debug mode using IISExpress.
- In command line, run cURL to reach your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add on the page that you call with curl one of this calls

```
Debug.Assert(false, "open debugger");
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

and the debugger will prompt you to use it.